# Multiple duplicate keychain DBs that don't get cleaned up

Tags: macos, mojave, keychain

Developing with [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), and as a result, I am creating `fastlane.keychain` keychain. Everytime it runs, it creates a new keychain with same name. OK, that's my fault.

However when I tried to delete the extra keychains, they don't go away. However the first command is successful, and subsequent commands say keychain is not found.

```
InterMacMini:Keychains user$ security delete-keychain fastlane.keychain-db
InterMacMini:Keychains user$ security list-keychains -d user
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/fastlane.keychain-db"
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/fastlane.keychain-db"
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/fastlane.keychain-db"
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/fastlane.keychain-db"
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/fastlane.keychain-db"
    "/Users/user/Library/Keychains/fastlane.keychain-db"
InterMacMini:Keychains user$ security delete-keychain fastlane.keychain-db
security: SecKeychainDelete: The specified keychain could not be found
```

Funny enough, Keychain Access app only shows 1 fastlane keychain

[image]